If Gal(K,F)=1 then K is a splitting field over F
I found a question asking whether or not this statement is true:
“If K extension of F with Gal(K,F)=1 then K is splitting field over F.”
My thought was that if Gal(K,F)=1 then K=F but that doesn’t give us that it would be splitting field. Any ideas?

This is false, assuming that $Gal(K,F)$ means the group of $F$-algebra automorphisms of $K$. Take $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.
I let you to check that your condition is fulfilled but that $K/F$ is not a normal extension, so it cannot be a splitting field of a polynomial over $F$.

Thanks for your answer, but if we consider f(x)=x^3 -2 then K is not a splitting field over F? Also why is Gal(K,F)=1 in this occasion?
